# How to activate automatic angle bracket `<>` pairing completion in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I just couldn't find out how to activate automatic angle bracket `<>` pairing in Visual Studio Code 
like it exists for parentheses `{}`, round `()` or box `[]` bracket. Anyone has any clue, where in the **setting** I could configure this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no setting in vscode that allows you to change what is considered to be a bracket, like adding `<>`.

There is an issue [Autoclosing pairs should be configurable](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38352)  that discusses this and you may wish to upvote it.  In that issue, it is mentioned that you could edit the language configuration file to add your own "brackets" to the list.  On Windows the javascript language configuration file is located at:

```
C: \Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\javascript-language-configuration.json;
```

as are the other languages (you don't say which language(s) you are interested in).  Javascript doesn't normally support bracket matching for `<>` but I added that functionality by editing the file like so:

```
{
    "comments": {
        "lineComment": "//",
        "blockComment": [ "/*", "*/" ]
    },
    "brackets": [
        ["<", ">"],                       // added
        ["{", "}"],
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ],
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        { "open": "<", "close": ">" },    // added
        { "open": "{", "close": "}" },
        { "open": "[", "close": "]" },
        { "open": "(", "close": ")" },
        { "open": "'", "close": "'", "notIn": ["string", "comment"] },
        { "open": "\"", "close": "\"", "notIn": ["string"] },
        { "open": "`", "close": "`", "notIn": ["string", "comment"] },
        { "open": "/**", "close": " */", "notIn": ["string"] }
    ],
    "surroundingPairs": [
        ["<", ">"],                       // added
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["'", "'"],
        ["\"", "\""],
        ["`", "`"]
    ],
    "autoCloseBefore": ";:.,=}])>` \n\t",
    "folding": {
        "markers": {
            "start": "^\\s*//\\s*#?region\\b",
            "end": "^\\s*//\\s*#?endregion\\b"
        }
    }
}
```

and it works - after a **reload**, demo in javascript file:

[image: angle bracket demo]

Now, this file **will** be overwritten on updates so I would keep a copy around elsewhere with a pointer to its location.

---

The other option - not as nice, no surround feature for example, is to make a snippet with `<` as the prefix (in one of your snippets files).

```
"angle bracket": {
  "prefix": "<",
  "body": [
    "<>"
  ],
  "description": "complete angle bracket"
},
```

After you type <kbd><</kbd> you will have to <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete it.  this also works.

Comment: I‘m looking for C++, it‘s quite annoying to work using STL, and keeps the pairing. I haven‘t try your solution yet, but I‘m satisfied with your answer. Thanks..

Comment: Anybody know where this file is on macOS?

Comment: @Merchako You could search for `language-onfiguration.json` on your OS or use this extension: `Custom Language Properties` which has a command to open the current editors language configurqtion file: `Show Language Configuration for Current Editor`.  You can modify the file there or from the tab context menu get the path.

Comment: Thank you, @Mark. I think it'll have to be the later since I read the *language-configuration.json* files get overwritten every time its corresponding extension is updated.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Like that]

if I understood correctly well it s in settings - text editor - automatic brace completion

Comment: Is that Visual Studio Code?  Or Visual Studio?

Comment: What? Why did you asked this? What’s the purpose?

Comment: He is asking how to do it in VSCode.

Comment: @iPhone7Plus : sorry, but I‘m looking for a setting in Visual Studio *Code* It is a different editor. (Well,  VS is an IDE, not editor, but anyway).

Comment: aaaahhh. Sry. Ye, I figured.

Comment: I did not downvote.!!!  I think you can figure out who probably did...  And it is probably appropriate to do so since "Visual Studio Code" is mentioned in the question and is a tag to the question.  I just asked where you got that Options dialog.

Comment: You don't want people confused by your answer and looking for that dialog or settings.  That is the point of downvotes.

Comment: If you don't like people downvoting it you can delete this answer if it's not very helpful to other users who are looking into solving the same problem