# Add closing bracket on press opening bracket

Tags: python, tkinter, text, brackets

Alright, so in VSCode, when you use an opening bracket, it automatically uses a closing bracket. Instead, I want this to be angle brackets. How would I do this? For example:

Presses: `<`

Output: `<>`

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm going to clarify this. I'm doing this in a Tkinter text widget. So pressing `<` will insert a `>`. Soory for the lack of clarity.

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068072/how-to-activate-automatic-angle-bracket-pairing-completion-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I'm trying to make a system like it in a window outside VSCode. I'm not trying to enable it in VSCode :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really simple solution is to bind a function to `<KeyRelease>`, since that will fire after the default bindings have actually inserted the character into the widget. Or, you could bind to `<KeyPress>` and manage inserting both the start original character and its closing character.

Let's start by defining a dictionary which defines which characters have matching characters. In this case we'll just use {} and <> for simplicity:

```
matched_pairs = {"{": "}", "<": ">"}
```

Next, lets define a function which examines the event to see if it is for a character which in in our dictionary. If we find a matching character we do two things: we insert the matching character, then move the insertion point back one so that the insertion character is between the pairs of characters.

```
def maybe_insert_matching_pair(event):
    matching = matched_pairs.get(event.char, None)
    if matching:
        event.widget.insert("insert", matching)
        event.widget.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c")
```

Finally, let's bind this function to every keypress, though you could also bind it to only the keys that you know have matching pairs.

```
the_text_widget.bind('<KeyRelease>', maybe_insert_matching_pair)
```